# control two data table with single input in shiny web

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

As i have written code to control single data table and the code is

under ui:

```
library(shiny)
fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title=h2(" Lucas Tvs",align="center")),
  sidebarPanel(
   conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs1=='profitloss'",
          selectInput("Operations","Select the desired ProfitLoss statement",choices = profitloss1$Operations)),
 conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs1=='Ratio'",
      selectInput("Ratio","Select the desired Ratios",choices=ratios1$Ratios)),

 conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs1=='Balancesheet'",
    selectInput("Particulars","Select the desired Balancesheet statement", choices = Balancesheet$Particulars))

     ),

    mainPanel(

    tabsetPanel(id="tabs1", 

   tabPanel("profitloss",column(5,tableOutput("profitloss")), column(7,plotOutput("plot"))),
   tabPanel("Ratio",column(5,tableOutput("Ratio")),column(6,plotOutput("plot2"))),
   tabPanel("Balancesheet",column(5,tableOutput("Balancesheet")),column(6,plotOutput("plot1")))

    )      

)
)
```

under sever:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
shinyServer(function(input,output){
    output$profitloss<-renderTable({
      oporationfilter<-profitloss1[profitloss1$Operations==input$Operations,c("Years","Value")]

    })
    output$Ratio<-renderTable({
      ratiofilter<-ratios1[ratios1$Ratios==input$Ratio,c("Years","Value")]
    })

    output$Balancesheet<-renderTable({
      Balancesheetfilter<-Balancesheet[Balancesheet$Particulars==input$Particulars,c("Years","Value")]
    })

    output$plot<-renderPlot({
      options(scipen = 999)
      p<-ggplot(data = profitloss1[profitloss1$Operations==input$Operations,]
                ,aes(x=Years,y=Value))
      p+geom_line()+xlab("Years")+ylab("Value in Lakhs")+ggtitle("Profitloss Plot")
     })



    output$plot2<-renderPlot({
      q<-ggplot(data = ratios1[ratios1$Ratios==input$Ratio,]
                ,aes(x=Years,y=Value))
      q+geom_line()+xlab("Years")+ylab("value in lakhs")+ggtitle("Ratios Plot ")
    })

    output$plot1<-renderPlot({
      q<-ggplot(data = Balancesheet[Balancesheet$Particulars==input$Particulars,]
                ,aes(x=Years,y=Value))
      q+geom_line()+xlab("Years")+ylab("value in lakhs")+ggtitle("Balance sheet Plot")
    })
  })
```

And now i want to add one more table in a main panel but control will be from a single input.
its mean if i click on operations of profitloss1 or ratios....then that will show me two table with a single click.

Comment: please help someone.I am not able to get out of it.